# PowerShell FTP upload not working - Creating zero byte file

Tags: windows, powershell, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I am working on a PowerShell script that is run from another application that is called after a success event and executes a series of commands:

1. First it zips a designated file (`ExampleFile`)
2. Then deleted the original
3. Uploads the zipped file to a server through FTP

My problem starts during the FTP process: as it exists below - the ZIP file is created correctly in the local system, and a ZIP file is created on the FTP server but it's stuck with a filesize of 0 bytes.

From the server, it looks like the upload hangs?

So: Lines 1-3 all work fine and the local zipped file has a non-zero size.

```
Add-Type -A 'System.IO.Compression.FileSystem';
[IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory("ExampleFolder\ExampleFile", "ExampleFolder\ExampleFile_Datestamp.zip");
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force "ExampleFolder\ExampleFile"; 

$Username = "exampleusername"; 
$Password = "examplepassword";
$LocalFile = "C:\Users\example_path\ExampleFolder\ExampleFile.zip";
$RemoteFile = "ftp://exampleserver/examplepath2/ExampleFile_Datestamp.zip";

$FTPRequest = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::Create("$RemoteFile");
$FTPRequest = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]$FTPRequest; 
$FTPRequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::UploadFile;
$FTPRequest.Credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $Password); 
$FTPRequest.UseBinary = $true; 
$FTPRequest.UsePassive = $true; 

$FileContent = gc -en byte $LocalFile; 
$FTPRequest.ContentLength = $FileContent.Length; 

$Run = $FTPRequest.GetRequestStream(); 
$Run.Write($FileContent, 0, $FileContent.Length); 
$Run.Close(); 
$Run.Dispose();
```

This has me pretty well stumped, so any ideas or thoughts appreciated.

```
powershell.exe -nologo -noprofile -command "Add-Type -A 'System.IO.Compression.FileSystem'; [IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory(\"ExampleFolder\ExampleFile\", \"ExampleFolder\ExampleFile_Datestamp.zip\"); Remove-Item -Recurse -Force \"ExampleFolder\ExampleFile\"; $Username = \"exampleusername\"; $Password = \"examplepassword\"; $LocalFile = \"C:\Users\example_path\ExampleFolder\ExampleFile.zip\"; $RemoteFile = \"ftp://exampleserver/examplepath2/ExampleFile_Datestamp.zip\"; $FTPRequest = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::Create(\"$RemoteFile\"); $FTPRequest = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]$FTPRequest; $FTPRequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::UploadFile; $FTPRequest.Credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $Password); $FTPRequest.UseBinary = $true; $FTPRequest.UsePassive = $true; $FileContent = gc -en byte $LocalFile; $FTPRequest.ContentLength = $FileContent.Length; $Run = $FTPRequest.GetRequestStream(); $Run.Write($FileContent, 0, $FileContent.Length); $Run.Close(); $Run.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a call to [`FtpWebRequest.GetResponse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest.getresponse):

```
...

$Run = $FTPRequest.GetRequestStream(); 
$Run.Write($FileContent, 0, $FileContent.Length); 
$Run.Close(); 

$FTPResponse = $FTPRequest.GetResponse()

Write-Out $FTPResponse.StatusCode
Write-Out $FTPResponse.StatusDescription
```

---

See [How to: Upload Files with FTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-upload-files-with-ftp).

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately, the additions were unsuccessful. I wish I could provide an error or log response, but the nature of the 3rd party call doesn't give me much. The ZIP file looks like it was still created, but still has a 0 file size.
Additionally, When we run our code line by line in the PowerShell, it works fine: writes the file and it's contents - it's only when we put it in the application that it's not writing the contents. If it helps, the 3rd parts is the RETS connector "on sucess" callback. 
Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Try to remove the `.Dispose` call, it should not be there (I did already in my response).

Comment: I removed the $Run.Dispose() call with no noticeable effects, and unfortunately the FTP is still not writing the file contents. My current line of thought might be a conflict/disruption in the nested quotes present in the original question, question above edited to add both to reflect both formats for full disclosure and syntax ease.